# Convertir SQL a Mongo

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, datatables, migration

Estoy convirtiendo algunas consultas de SQL a Mongo, pude resolver casi todas a excepción de 3 queries.
No estoy encontrando la forma para poder hacer comparaciones con valores embebidos de diferentes colecciones. Me quede atascado al no encontrar la forma de hacer subconsultas como en SQL.

Este es uno de los queries que llegue a resolver

- Mostrar todos los clientes que tengan al menos 1 doc

```
SELECT * 
FROM client 
WHERE nro_client IN (
    SELECT nro_client FROM doc
);
```

En Mongo

```
db.clients.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "doc",
        "localField": "nro_client",
        "foreignField": "nro_client",
        "as": "docs"
     }
}]).find({ "docs": { "$size": { "$gt": 0 } } }, { "docs": -1 })
```

Estos 3 son los que no logro encontrar la lógica para resolver

- Productos que estén en al menos 1 doc

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE product_code IN (
    SELECT product_code FROM doc
);
```

- Docs con al menos un artículo de la marca 'in Faucibus Inc's products

```
SELECT * 
FROM doc 
WHERE doc_nro IN (
    SELECT d.doc_nro 
    FROM line d 
    JOIN product p 
        ON d.product_code = p.product_code 
    WHERE p.brand = 'In Faucibus Inc.'
);
```

- Clientes y la suma del total de todos sus docs

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, f.total 
FROM client c 
JOIN (
    SELECT nro_client, SUM(total_w_iva) AS total 
    FROM docs 
    GROUP BY nro_client
) AS f 
    ON c.nro_client = f.nro_client;
```

Las colecciones que estoy usando en Mongo son:

```
"client": {
    "nro_client": 1,
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "direction": "",
    "active": 1,
    "tels": [{
        "area": 1,
        "nro_tel": 1,
        "type": ""
    }]
}

"product": {
    "product_code": 1,
    "brand": "",
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "pricce": 1.0,
    "stock": 1
}

"doc": {
    "nro_doc": 1,
    "date": "2022-1-1",
    "total_wo_iva": 0.0,
    "total_w_iva": 0.0,
    "iva": 1,
    "nro_client": 1,
    "lineds": [{
        "nro_item": 1,
        "quantity": 1.0,
        "product_code": 1
    }]
}
```